# convertView received in Adapter is of the wrong type

Tags: android, custom-adapter

I have custom adapter for spinner:

```
public class AreaArrayAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<__KeyValueObject[]> {

    private static final int ITEM_TYPE_AREA = 0;
    private static final int ITEM_TYPE_REGION = 1;

    private static final int NO_OF_TYPES = 2;

    private LayoutInflater mLayoutInflater;
    private __KeyValueObject[] mItems;

    public AreaArrayAdapter(Context context, int resource, __KeyValueObject[] items) {
        super(context, resource);
        mItems = items;
        mLayoutInflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemViewType(int position) {
        int type = -1;
        if (mItems[position].bool_val == true) {
            type = ITEM_TYPE_REGION;
        } else {
            type = ITEM_TYPE_AREA;
        }
        return type;
    }

    @Override
    public View getDropDownView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        return getCustomView(position, convertView, parent);
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        return getCustomView(position, convertView, parent);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean areAllItemsEnabled() {
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isEnabled(int position) {
        if (mItems[position].bool_val == true) {
            return true;
        } else {
            return true;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return mItems.length;
    }

    @Override
    public int getViewTypeCount() {
        return NO_OF_TYPES;
    }

    public View getCustomView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        int type = getItemViewType(position);

        if (type == ITEM_TYPE_AREA) {
            ViewHolderArea holderArea = null;
            if (convertView == null) {
                holderArea = new ViewHolderArea();
                convertView = mLayoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.row_spinner_area_item, null);
                holderArea.tvAreaItem = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.tvAreaItem);
                convertView.setTag(holderArea);
            } else {
                holderArea = (ViewHolderArea) convertView.getTag();
            }
            holderArea.tvAreaItem.setText(mItems[position].value);
        } else // type == ITEM_TYPE_REGION
        {
            ViewHolderRegion holderRegion = null;
            if (convertView == null) {
                holderRegion = new ViewHolderRegion();
                convertView = mLayoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.row_spinner_region_item, null);
                holderRegion.tvRegionItem = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.tvRegionItem);
                convertView.setTag(holderRegion);
            } else {
                holderRegion = (ViewHolderRegion) convertView.getTag();
            }
            holderRegion.tvRegionItem.setText(mItems[position].value);
        }

        return convertView;
    }

    public static class ViewHolderArea {
        public TextView tvAreaItem;
    }

    public static class ViewHolderRegion {
        public TextView tvRegionItem;
    }
}
```

here is my data:

```
 public static __KeyValueObject[] AREA = {
            new __KeyValueObject(50, "Region 1", true),
            new __KeyValueObject(100, "area 1-1"),
            new __KeyValueObject(200, "area 1-2"),
            new __KeyValueObject(300, "area 1-3"),
            new __KeyValueObject(800, "Region 2", true),
            new __KeyValueObject(900, "area 2-1"),
            new __KeyValueObject(1000, "area 2-2"),
            new __KeyValueObject(1100, "area 2-3"),
            new __KeyValueObject(1200, "area 2-4")
}
```

When I press the Spinner for some reason in `getCustomView` the first call goes right. The second call to `getCustomView` the item I get is of type `ITEM_TYPE_AREA` but the `convertView` I get is of type `ViewHolderRegion` so trying to cast : `holderArea = (ViewHolderArea) convertView.getTag();` crashes.

Any idea why `convertView` received is of the wrong type?

Comment: Is your 2 argument constructor for `__KeyValueObject` setting `bool_val` to **false**?

Comment: try replace `else` with `if`  condition like `if (type ==ITEM_TYPE_REGION)`

Comment: @JimRhodes yes, bool_val is set to false by default.

Comment: @dsb, your code looks correct to me. If you haven't solved this problem yet, post the code for your __KeyValueObject class. You may also want to add some logging to getItemViewType to make sure you are getting the correct type for each position. Or set a breakpoint there.

Comment: @JimRhodes thank you for your help. The code still does not work for me. The implementation of ExternalLoginCallback is very simple: public class __KeyValueObject {
    public __KeyValueObject(int key, String value, Boolean bool_val) {
        this.key = key;
        this.value = value;
        this.bool_val = bool_val;
    }

    public __KeyValueObject(int key, String value) {
        this.key = key;
        this.value = value;
        this.bool_val = false;
    }

    public int key;
    public String value;
    public boolean bool_val;

}. Any suggestion?

Answer (score 0):

If you receive convertView and getItemViewType(position) == ITEM_TYPE_REGION it doesn't mean that this view contain in Tag ViewHolderRegion, because views are reuse. so you need each time inflate new view or create common ViewHolder

```
public static class ViewHolder {
    public TextView tvAreaItem;
    public TextView tvRegionItem;
}
```

Update:
Look at this [tutorial](http://android.amberfog.com/?p=296)

Comment: Thank you. I have lots of experience with Custom Adapters and I am familiar with this Tutorial. However, in the past when I used more than one type of items I always received the correct type of convertView. For X number of types Android manages X lists of reusable objects and sends the correct type to getView(...). Not this time! and I can't see where the is the mistake I am doing. It is surely something in my code.

Comment: @dsb I think you should refresh you knowledge about ViewHolder pattern.